# Print lines before and after matching regexp in TCL

Tags: regex, file, tcl

I want to be able to print 10 lines before and 10 lines after I come across a matching pattern in a file. I'm matching the pattern via regex. I would need a TCL specific solution. I basically need the equivalent of the **grep -B 10 -A 10** feature.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the data is “relatively small” (which can actually be 100MB or more on modern computers) then you can load it all into Tcl and process it there.

```
# Read in the data
set f [open "datafile.txt"]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Find which lines match; adjust to taste
set matchLineNumbers [lsearch -all -regexp $lines $YourPatternHere]
# Note that the matches are already in order

# Handle overlapping ranges!
foreach n $matchLineNumbers {
    set from [expr {max(0, $n - 10)}]
    set to [expr {min($n + 10, [llength $lines] - 1)}]
    if {[info exists prev] && $from <= $prev} {
        lset ranges end $to
    } else {
        lappend ranges $from $to
    }
    set prev $to
}

# Print out the ranges
foreach {from to} $ranges {
    puts "=== $from - $to ==="
    puts [join [lrange $lines $from $to] "\n"]
}
```

Comment: I get the following error on set matchLineNumbers [lsearch -all -regexp $lines $YourPatternHere]

wrong # args: should be "lsearch ?mode? list pattern"

Comment: @junosman You must be using a very old version of Tcl. The `-all` option was introduced in 8.4…

Answer (score 0):

The only mechanism that springs to mind is for you to split the input data into a list of lines. You'd then need to sweep through the list and whenever you found a match output a suitable collection of entries from the list.

To the best of my knowledge there's no built-in, easy way of doing this.

There might be something useful in `tcllib`.

I'd use `grep` myself.

Comment: I can't really use grep or tcllib. I'm not sure how to go about it via splitting the input data though.

Comment: Donal's fuller answer below shows how to split the lines; if you can't pick it out of the wealth of detail it's `set lines [split [read $f] \n]`. `[read $f]` returns all the data from the file, and `[split ... \n]` turns that data into a list, where the newlines in the input data are removed and delimit the list entries. Good luck.